# Do two equivalent actions lead to the same expectation values?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, action

The title is a bit short for what I want to know so here is the setup:

Let's assume we have two actions $S_1[\phi]$ and $S_2[\phi_1,\phi_2]$ that are equivalent (lead to the same equations of motion) when a constraint $f(\phi_1,\phi_2)=0$ is satisfied. In principle if the equations of motion are the same, the expectation values would be the same. But using these two different actions before using the constraint we arrive at
\begin{align*}
\langle F[\phi]\rangle_a &= \frac{\int \mathcal{D} \phi\,F[\phi]e^{iS_1[\phi]}}{\int \mathcal{D} \phi\,e^{iS_1[\phi]}}
\\
\langle F[\phi_1,\phi_2]\rangle_b &= \frac{\int \mathcal{D} \phi_1 \mathcal{D} \phi_2\,F[\phi_1,\phi_2]e^{iS_2[\phi_2,\phi_2]}}{\int \mathcal{D} \phi_1 \mathcal{D} \phi_2\,e^{iS_2[\phi_1,\phi_2]}},
\end{align*}
where $F[\phi]=F[\phi_1,\phi_2]$ (we can assume that $\phi=\phi_1$ for example). If $S_2$ is a sum of two terms $T[\phi_1]+T[\phi_2]$ then the expectation values are the same but what if $S_2$ is not a sum of such two terms?

---

Background :

In fact, this question arose in my head when I was thinking about the Einstein-Hilbert action and the Palatini action. An equivalent and more concrete formulation of the question would be the question of the truthfulness of the following equality (regardless of the precise meaning of what such functional integrals represent):
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\int \mathcal{D}g\,g_{\mu \nu}e^{\frac{i}{2 \kappa}\int d^4x\,\sqrt{-g}R}}{\int \mathcal{D}g\,e^{\frac{i}{2 \kappa}\int d^4x\,\sqrt{-g}R}}\stackrel{?}{=}\eta_{IJ}\frac{\int \mathcal{D}e\mathcal{D}\omega\,e^I_\mu e^J_\nu e^{\frac{i}{2\kappa}\int d^4x\,e\,e^\alpha_K e^\beta_L \Omega_{\alpha \beta}^{KL}}}{\int \mathcal{D}e\mathcal{D}\omega\,e^{\frac{i}{2\kappa}\int d^4x\,e\,e^\alpha_K e^\beta_L \Omega_{\alpha \beta}^{KL}}},
\end{equation*}
where one imposes afterward $d_\omega e=0$, and with $\Omega=d_\omega \omega$. With the constraint $d_\omega e=0$ the Einstein-Hilbert action and the Palatini action lead to the same equations of motion. I think the two sides must be equal but it seems not trivial (at least for me).

Comment: Naively, I would not expect the expectation value to be the same for the two actions. The "equivalence" of the actions is only classical because the reasoning to judge that they are equivalent is the equality of classical equations of motion (the EL equations). Correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: Definitely not. Filling in details from the previous comment, consider the trivial case where your constraint is $f(\phi_1, \phi_2) = \phi_2 = 0$, i.e. $\phi_2$ is gapped and removed entirely. If one integrates out $\phi_2$, one will generically generate quantum corrections to the bare parameters of your theory (unless $\phi_1$ doesn't with $\phi_2$, which is the case when $S_2$ is purely a sum of terms as you mention), thus driving you to different theory (i.e. different expectation values).

Comment: @Aaron So, for my example with Einstein-Hilbert and Palatini actions, since the theory must be compatible with fermions, the RHS is a better quantity than the LHS?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by "better," the Palatini action is a generalization of the E-H action which at least reproduces the classical results of E-H, allowing things like fermionic fields which makes Palatini nice. Without any experimental evidence of a quantum theory of gravity, however, it's hard to know what is "better." Admittedly, I'm not much of a GR or GR-QFT person, but my understanding is that any quantum corrections to gravitational actions are fraught with issues anyways so expectation values beyond classical level aren't meaningful in the first place.